# How to restore deleted partion table

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery, testdisk

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, from past 2 days I am not able to boot the system but when I checked connecting the hard disk in other system it was showing below error message.

```
Disk /dev/sdc doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

When I checked with testdisk It was showing all the partition table.

```
Disk /dev/sdc - 500 GB / 465 GiB - CHS 60801 255 63
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
   Linux                    0  32 33  6224 210  2   99999744
   Linux Swap            6224 210  3  6722 163 33    7997440
>  Linux                 6722 196  3 25396 186  6  299997184
   Linux                25396 218 39 31621 141  8   99999744
   Linux Swap           31621 141  9 32119  94 39    7997440
   Linux                32119 127  9 44277  54  1  195313664 [data]
```

How to re-create the partition table without loosing the data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I checked with `testdisk` It was showing all the partition table

Awesome, you're in a good situation.

> How to re-create the partition table without loosing the data ?

Just go on with the [Testdisk step-by-step procedure](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) and **write** the table on the disk (it's the last step).

From the aforementioned link:

> ### Save the partition table or search for more partitions?
>
> [image: partitions list]
>
> - ***When all partitions are available*** and data correctly listed, you should go to the menu **Write** to save the partition structure.
>     The menu `Extd Part` gives you the opportunity to decide if the
>     extended partition will use all available disk space or only the
>     required (minimal) space.
>
> [...]
>
> - If **all partitions are listed** and only in this case, confirm at ***Write*** with Enter, y and OK.